# Output keeps moving to next line

Tags: java, formatting, output

I'm having an issue whereby my output upon printing moves to the next line on its own, not the entire line moves, but parts of it. I would like it to be on the same line.

I've tried searching for similar issues online but no luck, I've also double checked my code, it shouldn't be moving to the next line for no reason. I would appreciate some insight on this, perhaps i'm too inexperienced to notice my error. This is what I have: Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    //for loop to repeat 5 times
    for (int i= 1; i < 6; i++)
   {            
    //create 2 new points to use as argument
    Point p1 = new Point();
    Point p2 = new Point();

    //create array to store return values, call method to generate points
    Point point[] = getTwoPoints(p1, p2);

    System.out.println("Set:" + i);
    System.out.print("Given Point:" + "(" + point[0] + ")");
    System.out.print("Given Point:"+ "(" + point[1]+ ")");

    System.out.print("Line:" + "("+ point[0]+ ")" + "(" + point[1] + ")");
    System.out.printf("Distance:"+"%.4f", point[0].getDistance(point[1]));
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("==================================");
   }
}
```

Sample Output:

```
Set:1
Given Point:(60,57
)Given Point:(-75,83
)Line:(60,57
)(-75,83
)Distance:137.4809
```

Answer (score 3):

What's the implementation of `Point::toString` method?

Most likely it contains a `\n` in it. Thus each time you print a point the caret goes to the next line.

Comment: This was it, thanks so much! I must have been blind.

Comment: @B.Rain Yeah, it happens sometimes.